# Polly does not retry even though an exception is caught

Tags: c#, timeout, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

I have the following configuration of my HTTP service:

```cs
services
   .AddHttpClient<ISomeHttpService, SomeHttpService>((Action<HttpClient>) (client =>
      {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration.BaseAddress);
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
      }))
  .AddPolicyHandler(GetPollyPolicy())
  .AddHttpMessageHandler<DistributedCachedHttpClientHandler>();

// .....


private static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetPollyPolicy()
{
    return HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .OrInner<Exception>() // I will probably use TimeoutException, for now I'm checking all possible options
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(2, _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), 
        (exception, timeSpan) =>
        {
           _ = "breakpoint";
        });
}
```

It works really well, if the request made by `SomeHttpService` returns 500. Polly tries to retry 2 more times.

However, if the request takes more time than 10 seconds (which is more than the configured timeout), retries do not occur. I even set a breakpoint within the Polly's action and I see that the breakpoint is hit when the timeout occurs! However, when I continue the program, no retries are executed and my web API fails with 500 directly after.

What's wrong?

I also tried using `Or<Exception>()` instead of `OrInner<Exception>()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: The observed behaviour is the way how `HttpClient`'s `Timeout` overarches all retry attempts.

---

The root cause of your problem is that `HttpClient`'s `Timeout` is considered as global rather than local timeout:

- Global means overarching, includes all the retry attempts
- Local means per retry attempt

If you want to define a local timeout then you have to combine Retry and [Timeout](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout) policies:

```
var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(5);
var retryPolicy = HttpPolicyExtensions
    .HandleTransientHttpError()
    .OrInner<TimeoutRejectedException>()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(2, _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));

var combinedPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(retryPolicy, timeoutPolicy);
```

Please note that the order of the parameters of the `Policy.WrapAsync` matters.

The above example defines a per request timeout policy (*inner*) and a retry policy (outer), which is aware of the potential timeout (`TimeoutRejectedException`).

You can define two timeout policies, where one acts locally whereas the other acts globally:

```
var combinedPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(globalTimeout, retryPolicy, localTimeout);
```

Comment: That's a cool answer, thanks! Do I understand correctly that your last example (with `globalTimeout`) should be used when I'd like to have some smaller local timeout and some greater global timeout which will cause the whole policy to stop when it's crossed?

Comment: @mnj Either use HttpClient's Timeout with some greater timespan or define a global timeout policy. Both work fine, the difference is thrown exception: OperationCanceledException vs TimeoutRejectedException.